# A graph such that each vertex has 36 neighbors

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math

Let $G$ be a simple graph such that each vertex in $G$ has exactly $36$ neighbors. Further for vertices $X,Y$, if $X$ is neighbor to $Y$, there are exactly $18$ other vertices that are neighbors to both $X$ and $Y$; and if $X$  is not neighbor to $Y$, there are exactly $4$ other vertices that are neighbors to both $X$ and $Y$. Determine the number of vertices in $G$.

So far, I obtain the relation $n=18m$, where $m$ is the number of edges in $G$, by counting triangles in $G$ and could not move forward. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem describes a [strongly regular graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_regular_graph) $\operatorname{srg}(v,k=36,\lambda=18,\mu=4)$. All srgs must satisfy (the proof of this relation is on Wikipedia as well)
$$(v-k-1)\mu=k(k-\lambda-1)$$
which here becomes
$$4(v-37)=36(17)$$
$$v=9×17+37=190$$